# Adding two numbers and show the output on the same page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am new to Django, I am not sure if I could do action and show result on the same page.
For this page I want to add two numbers that are entered on textarea a1 and a2 together, and output it on textarea a3.

Now, the error is showing Page not found (404), I guess it is something to do with my routing.

And if I am doing dynamic content like this, should I use VueJS or react instead?

Here is my view:

```
def add(request):
    """The Cipher and Decipher page"""
    res = 0
    val1 = int(request.GET.get('a1', 0))
    val2 = int(request.GET.get('a2', 0))
    res = val1 + val2

    return render(request, 'morse_logs/add.html', {'result': res})
```

my html (add.html):

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Addition</h1>
    <form action="add">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='a1' ></textarea>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='a2' ></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="add">Calculate</button>

        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="a3" >{{result}} </textarea>
    </form>
{% endblock content  %}
```

my url.py:

```
app_name = 'morse_logs'

urlpatterns = [
    # Home Page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # Page that shows all topics
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    # Page that do addition
    path('add/', views.add, name='add'),


]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify in form's action attribute url where form should be send. You have `add` here which is not valid url. Instead you can just put `""` here to show that form shoul be send to the current url:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Addition</h1>
    <form action="" method="get">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='a1' ></textarea>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='a2' ></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="add">Calculate</button>

        <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="a3" >{{result}} </textarea>
    </form>
{% endblock content  %}
```